# Тень изображения на pictureBox'e невидна на другом изображении, C#

Tags: c#, winforms

Столкнулся с такой проблемой и немогу пофиксить.

На форме есть 2 `pictureBox'a` - **скриншот 1**

Загружаются туда картинки вот так:

```
        imageList1.TransparentColor = Color.Transparent;
        pictureBox2.Image = imageList1.Images[0];
        pictureBox1.Image = imageList1.Images[1];
```

У всех `pictureBox` свойство `BackColor = Transparent`.

При сборке, вроде бы все ок - **скриншот 2**.

Но при перемещении, картинка с тенью "обрезает" вторую - **скриншот 3**.

Ну, а мне нужно, чтобы выглядело вот так (тень отбрасывалась на вторую картинку) - **скриншот 4**.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это реализовать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: WinForms или WPF?

Comment: Там Windows Forms.